# Javascript - how to check for 2 conditions on form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, conditional-statements

We have a form where users can leave an opinion anonymously, but if they want to leave their email address for a follow up they can. If they choose to leave their email, we want them to check the box that they read our privacy policy. If they choose not to leave an email address they don't need to check the box.

Here is the Javascript code on the form page. It doesn't work with both conditions, I can only get it to work if the box is checked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function(event){
           if (!$("input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked")){
             if ($("input[name$='Mail']").val() !== "") {
             alert("内容に同意ください。");
             event.preventDefault();
         }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no `.value` property in jQuery object. Instead use `.val()` and use equality operators rather than assignment operators.

```
if (!$("input[name$='Mail']").val() === "") {
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition seems to be that if there is something in the e–mail field, then the checkbox must be checked. Presumably the form controls all have names (otherwise they aren't going to be successful) so the validation function can be really simple:

```
$("#form").submit(function(){

       // If there's something in the email fiend and the checkbox isn't checked
       // show the message
       if (this.emailControlName.value != '' && !this.checkboxName.checked) {
        alert("内容に同意ください。");
        return false;
      }
    }
});
```

The following "works" exactly as you require:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function(){
      if (this.email.value != '' && !this.readAgreement.checked){
        alert("内容に同意ください。");
        return false;
      }
    });
});
</script>

<form id="form">
  email:<textarea name="email"></textarea><br>
  read agreement:<input type="checkbox" name="readAgreement" value="yes"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Note that where you have:

```
if (!$("input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked")){
```

that checks the checked **attribute**, not the checked property. For the current version of jQuery (1.11), if the input doesn't have the checked attribute, i.e. is like the one in the form above, then `...attr('checked')` will return *undefined* and the expression resolves to *false*, even if the user checks the input.

Up to version 1.7 at least, jQuery confused attributes and properties and the *attr* method returned the checked property, not the attribute.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Would I change `this.emailControlName.value` to `input[name$='Mail']".val()` ?

Comment: That one looks like it would work, but I don't know how to label `this.emailControlName` and `this.checkboxName.checked`. I tried `this.Mail` for Mail and `thisCheckbox` with the above code, but no dice. :(

Comment: *emailControlName* is the **full** name of the form control that users enters the email into. Similarly for *checkboxName*, and *this* will reference the form. All form controls are available as named properties of the form (browsers have supported it since the very beginning). If the names aren't valid identifiers (e.g. if the mail one is named 'e–mail'), then use bracket notation: `this['e-mail'].value`.

Comment: that looks correct but I have one question. I'm currently using Kentico CMS for this form, so I can't use the `<textarea name="email">` tag. Kentico makes this type of thing vigorously complex; here is the web element for the input box for email address: `<input name="p$lt$zoneContent$pageplaceholder$pageplaceholder$lt$zoneMain$editabletext$widget1$ctl00$viewBiz$ctl00$Mail$textbox" type="text" maxlength="500" id="p_lt_zoneContent_pageplaceholder_pageplaceholder_lt_zoneMain_editabletext_widget1_ctl00_viewBiz_ctl00_Mail_textbox" class="TextBoxField">`  - How would apply the javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
if (!$("input[name$='Mail']").value = "") {
```

To be something like this instead:

```
if ($("input[name$='Mail']").val() !== "") {
```

Your version is assigning `""` to the value; since `""` evaluates as `false`, that `if` condition will never be true.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I've changed the code and it still doesn't work; if the `Mail` field is blank, it still asks me to check the box. I'll put the revised code in the question.

Comment: Have it `alert` what the `val()` actually is.

Comment: Is this how the line should read? `alert("input[name$='Mail']").val());`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ".is(":checked")" to check the state of check box as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#form").submit(function(event){
       if ($("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked")){
         if ($("input[name$='Mail']").val() !== "") {
         alert("内容に同意ください。");
         event.preventDefault();
     }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

If you want to check the checkbox only if mail is not empty then you will have to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#form").submit(function(event){
       if ($("input[name$='Mail']").val() !== "") {
         if ($("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked")){
         alert("内容に同意ください。");
         event.preventDefault();
     }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Each time, the result is the same; it doesn't matter if Mail is blank or not; the page requires the check box.

Comment: Welcome, and i did not completely understand you problem can you please elaborate it more.

Comment: sure, thanks for asking. What I want to do is have an optional line for users to leave an email address if they want to be contacted. But if they actually enter an address, they need to check a box stating that they've read our privacy policy. If they DON'T leave an email address, the checkbox can be blank.

Comment: then you will have to check if mail is not empty and  checkbox is checked also. like:  
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function(event){
       if ($("input[name$='Mail']").val() !== ""){
          if ($("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked")){
         alert("内容に同意ください。");
         event.preventDefault();
     }
    }
    });
    });
    </script>

Comment: Yes, that's correct. So far, what's happened is that if the checkbox isn't check, users are told they need to check it, even if there is nothing in "mail". Or, users enter an email address and they don't check the box but the form submits anyway.

Comment: I'm using a CMS - Kentico (pain in the a--). Do I need to add `<span>` tags to label the input boxes? Kentico sets up their forms as `$$input:Mail$$` so I've just been using `Mail` as my identifier.

Comment: can you please provide me the html of mail textbox created by kentico

Comment: sure: `<td>$$input:Mail$$$$validation:Mail$$</td>`

Comment: Thank you for providing the html, but can you please inspect element from Chrome or Firefox over mail textbox and give me that html that what the final html is created.